# Named volumes on desired location

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I need to store the project on the mounted drive using the docker-compose file, placed at the root of that drive. I want to use docker volumes, not as bounded folders, but as named volumes. But I do not want to store it physically on the default location (/var/lib/docker/volume), because the system drive is small. How can I set up named volumes in docker-compose and ask the docker to create volumes in the same place where the docker-compose file is located?

Comment: It seems like bind mounts are an easy way to specify the host storage location; why not use them?  (The one thing special about named volumes is the ability to copy the image content, but that content never gets updated and this functionality doesn't work on any other storage system, so I'd avoid relying on this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommended**: If system drive is small then you should move the docker data-root to some other location. This will keep compose file same across all users/systems.

**Not Recommended**: For having a named volume on desired location, you can specify `driver_opts` for the volume driver.

e.g. for `local` driver, declare top level volumes in compose file as

```
volumes:
  my_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: "/full/host/path/"
      o: bind
```

This change will apply to all systems your docker compose is used, with small system drives or large.